# PowerShell multiple Threads: communication

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I remember from Perl on Linux that threads need e.g. named pipes to communicate with each other.
Is this the same with PowerShell on Windoww?

Or is there a 'place' of e.g. common global variables which could be accessed (how?) by all threads?

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

PS: For a better understanding:
My script has to open 2 client-socket connections (to aremote ip) and 1 local named pipe.
Beside others it shall manage and forward the orders from the pipe to the sockets - all nonblocking.
So my problem do I need several threads? If so they need to exchange their data.

Comment: What are you [really after](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Well my script has to open 2 client-socket connections (remote ip) and 1 local named pipe. Beside others it shall manage and forward the orders from the pipe to the sockets - all nonblocking. So my problem do I need several threads? If so they need to exchange their datas.